# How to use "What exactly"

Tags: sentence-structure

I'd like to know if this question is correct or not:

> What exactly that you don't like about my clothes?

I know I can also ask:

> What is it that you don't like about my clothes, exactly?

But I'd like to remove this dummy "it" and I'd like to use "exactly" right after "what". How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question is incorrectly phrased. The second is grammatical, but clumsy.

You can remove the dummy "it", and place "exactly" right after "what", with

> What exactly don't you like about my clothes?

Comment: Or **What exactly do you not like about my clothes?**

Comment: @MichaelRybkin Your comment is really helpful, thank you.